# How do I troubleshoot my Kenmore dryer that doesn't heat up?

Tags: appliances, dryer

I have a Kenmore 110.64642400 that has just started acting up.

It spins fine, using the timed dry function the timer knob advances (although not in the auto dry function), but it never heats up.

I've read that it could be the heating element, thermostat or timer. I already checked the breakers (not blown, switched on and off for good measure).

I've got the back panel off, but I'm at a loss as to what to check for next. How do I go about looking at one of these 3 potential issues to find the solution? ([This thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/no-heat-on-dryer) didn't help me decipher what steps to take)

Comment: Is there a wiring diagram somewhere inside the machine? It would be either on the inside of the service panel, or in a little envelope taped somewhere inside the service panel.  Can you find any specifications for the heating element (voltage, amperage, wattage, resistance, etc.)?

Comment: Did you check the fuses in the dryer?  There should be 2, one for the motor, and one for the heater. Obviously, check the one for the heater. But if you're not sure which is which, check both. Depending on the model, the heater should be between 7.8-11.8 Ohms (a schematic will confirm this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I tested all of the leads I could find (heating element, thermostat, etc) and they all returned ~1.2 - 2.4 Ohms. I thought that was low because of what Tester101 said, but all of them being that value made me think it was ok.

I checked over the heating element for the 3rd time, and the coil had a break in it on the back side - it was hidden from plain sight. I replaced the heating element and all is working now.

Comment: What was the resistance of the new heating element? Did you isolate the element before testing it?

Comment: Did you get continuity on the coil?

Answer (score 2):

Some dryers have an in line thermal protection device that can go bad. Trace the wires to the element, or better yet refer to a wiring diagram. You would need an ohm meter to check for continuitiy.